# How to query a table with wildcard in the name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a bunch of tables, that have the same first few characters in the names, but the tables have random numbers (equal in length) at the end of the names.

They have the same structure.

I want to union them into one table, dynamically.

This is in SQL Server 2008 Express.

I have no real idea how to do this, but I'm guessing I have to loop thru a list of the tables names, maybe using a list in the system tables?

Example (that illustrates my simple minded thinking, as I'm sure this make no real technical sense)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE0*
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE0*
```

Note '*' is a a number with 8 digits.

Comment: Are the numbers truly random or follow some kind of logic/sequence?

Comment: Essentially logical, but I have no way to know ahead of time what they will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick dynamic SQL script should do it:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = ''

select @sql = @sql + case len(@sql) when 0 then '' else ' UNION ALL ' end + '
    SELECT * FROM [' + table_name + ']'
from
    information_schema.tables where table_name like 'TABLE0%'

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: This seems close, but I get an error.  "Incorrect sequence near the keyword ALL'

Comment: @AncientAnt: Fixed now

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple query like this to construct your large query:

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM '+name+ ' UNION '
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '%yourtable%'
```

Or you could use dynamic SQL to build it and run it:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = ''
SELECT @sql = @sql +'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM ['+name+']'
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '%yourtable%'
SET @sql = STUFF(@sql,1,15,'')
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: This seems close too, but I don't know how to get it from the table into query I can run, at least not dynamically.  Any pointers there?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I couldn't get this to work.  I'm sure it's on me somehow.